# Is it possible to change a user's Drupal password with Drush?

Tags: drupal, drush

Is it possible to change a user's Drupal password from the command-line with Drush?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you're running Drupal 7, using md5 won't work as passwords are salted. However, if you have drush 4.x, you can use the user-password command:

```
drush user-password someuser --password="gr3@tP@$s"
```

Comment: Just a note here: for those who fear carpal tunnel.

`drush upwd someuser --password="gr3@tP@$s"`

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Here's an example for resetting the password of the Drupal admin user given that you know the UserID (uid):

```
drush sqlq "update {users} set pass=md5('new_password_here') where uid=1"
```

Answer (score -2):

The Command goes like this:

drush user-password someuser --password="New Password-of yours"

You can change through Drsuh term

Comment: don't just post a duplicate of the top answer